# ASP.NET Core Web Socket Handling

Tags: c#, websocket

I am currently developing a client and server application where the applications are communicating over a web socket connection and it is working fine.  The layout of how this works look like:

[image: Application Diagram]
Currently the client application connects to a dedicated websocket endpoint in my ASP.NET Core webserver and they send messages back and forth in a closed loop. Once a client connects, the connection is cached into an Active Sockets collection on the server.  From that collection, I can find any socket client that is connected.

What I would like to do is expose the ability to talk with the socket client to the HTML front end (for example, a user might want to ping the socket client to retrieve a machine state or status).  Given that I have a dedicated websocket handler for all incoming messages, how would I wait for and retrieve the message with my controller?  I can send a message like so:

```
public async Task PingWorker(string key)
{
    //retrieve socket
    var clientRequired = ActiveSocketClients.GetClient(key);

    //send message to client using standard socket messaging
    await clientRequired.SendMessageAsync("CLIENT_STATUS");

    //somehow wait for a response, response is routed to a static handler

    //return message to user
}
```

The startup code that adds the websocket handler is:

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
     {
         if (context.Request.Path == "/ws")
         {
             if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
             {
                 WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                 SocketManagement socketManagement = new SocketManagement(cache);
                 await socketManagement.ProcessIncomingSocketMessage(context, webSocket);     
             }
             else
             {
                 context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             await next();
         }
     });
```

The socket handler code is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Processes incoming socket messages from clients
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
/// <param name="webSocket"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task ProcessIncomingSocketMessage(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
{       
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

    while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
    {
        //get connection information
        string connectionID = context.Connection.Id;
        string ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

        //retrieve value
        var arraySegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count);
        var incomingMessage = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(arraySegment.Array);
        incomingMessage = incomingMessage.Substring(0, result.Count);

        //convert client data
        var clientData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SocketPackage>(incomingMessage);

        //Continue processing message and reply

    }
}
```

Comment: You client is going to be a two port application.  One port to Websocket and one port to HTML webpage.  So you need to have an Application Layer that takes commands from the webpage and processes the commands.  Some of the commands will be forwarded to the WebSocket.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, but given the context above, how is my Controller call supposed to "wait" until the message is received?  That is my current problem... the controller needs to wait for the web socket response and maybe override or have the /ws handler reroute somehow?

Comment: That is what application layer does.  You should buy yourself a good College Level Communication Book and read it.  Are you implementing as synchronous or asynchronous interface.  So normally client sends a command.  Server Processes the command and send a response when command is completed.  The server can optionally send an Ack when receiving the command before doing the processing.  This is Communication Theory 101.

Comment: @jdweng I think you have missed what I am asking.  I understand the concepts of sockets and a web server... I have working code in the application layer as depicted above.  I just don't know what the best practice is in ASP MVC for what I am attempting to do.  My javascript ajax method calls the controller, the controller then calls   `await clientRequired.SendMessageAsync("CLIENT_STATUS");` which sends the message to the client, and the controller proceeds to return back to the javascript.  The issue is, how should I make the controller wait before returning back to the javascript?

Comment: @jdweng As I understand it, its not best practice to wait synchronously within a controller method.  Maybe I should make the `"Client_Status" call and let that call return, then start polling with another Ajax call to the controller to see if a response was received by the handler.  This is what I am asking. What should I do that is considered best practice?

Comment: I do not know if there is any standard practice.  I always think it is a good idea to keep the Network layers separated in this case application and transport layers.  so that implies using Asynchronous method for the transport layer.  The application layer should be a loop that read/writes data from/to the transport layer.  The loop should not continuously run.  So people put sleep in the loop.  I prefer the loop to have a block using WaitOne.  Then when the transport layer gets a new message Sets the Waitone so the application layer gets the response and continue with next command.